# I can't get value of this class

Tags: javascript

```js
class Progress {
    constructor(Max, Min) {
        this.Max = Max;
        this.Min = Min;
        this.current;
    }

    static get get() {
        //((input - min) * 100) / (max - min)
        return this.current;
    }

    static set Progress(number) {
        this.current = number;
    }
}

var prog = new Progress(0, 200);
prog.Progress = 22;
console.log(prog.get);
// console return 'undefined'
```

Any can help me with this.

I try to get the percent, of "Max" and "Min", but i can't get nothing

Comment: Try removing `static` from get and set.

Comment: Static methods has no access to `this`, since they are static. Also, because they are static, they belong to the class, not to the class instance, hence you can call them on `Progress` instead. I would suggest you to follow a beginner OOP tutorial, because this isn't strictly related to the javascript approach, but rather the OOP in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ## [Static](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static)
>
> The `static` keyword defines a static method for a class. Static methods aren't called on instances of the class. Instead, they're called on the class itself. These are often utility functions, such as functions to create or clone objects.

You have a problem because of the modifier `static`, basically, you're not calling the method/attribute `get` because you're trying to access an attribute which doesn't exist.

For example, to access the static method `get`, you have to execute the following:

```
Progress.get
```

Removing the modifier `static` everthing work well.

```js
class Progress {
  constructor(Max, Min) {
    this.Max = Max;
    this.Min = Min;
  }

  get get() {
    return this.current;
  }

  set Progress(number) {
    this.current = number;
  }
}

var prog = new Progress(0, 200);
prog.Progress = 22;
console.log(prog.get);
```

Comment: It Works, Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the static from get and set as static methods cannot access local variables

```
class Progress {
  constructor(Max, Min) {
    this.Max = Max;
    this.Min = Min;
    this.current;
  }

  get get() {
    //((input - min) * 100) / (max - min)
    return this.current;
  }

  set Progress(number) {
    this.current = number;
  }
}

var prog = new Progress(0, 200);
prog.Progress = 22;
console.log(prog.get);
```